# C# - Getting CURLException debug output

Tags: c#, curl, asp.net-core

I used dotnet-svcutil to generate client for wsdl web service. Web service requires client certificate to work. On linux server, following code throws exception without any useful info.

```
            string certPath = "cert.pfx";
            var client = new WebServiceClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(certPath, "password");
            var task = client.customOperationAsync();
            task.Wait();
            return task.Result;
```

Exception has multiple nested exceptions, the relevant one is `System.Net.Http.CurlException` - `Failure when receiving data from the peer`.

How can I fix this/gather more relevant information? `journalctl` is empty (as I'm catching the exception and returning it as `ObjectResult` in my Asp.Net Core application).

Comment: Why are you using task.Wait() and task.Result? Why are you using the *await* keyword to await the completion of the task?

Comment: I'ts not final code, it's more like "let's see if it works". I'll use await when I place the code in my model, but it's not necessary now. I have it in separate static method that I call from connector right now, because I've tried multiple approaches before and now I'm tired of writing good code just to see it doesn't even work.